# R-forge vs Rforge?

Tags: r

I am a novice to R package development.

I just wanted to know which one is better [R-forge](http://r-forge.r-project.org/) or [Rforge.net](http://www.rforge.net/)? What is the main difference between them?

Comment: I use R-forge but the R build system has been broken for several months with some packages building at certain times on certain OSes and not at other times etc. There are other infelicities, like the svn revision counters not incrementing in the web side of the site, but these are minor. At the moment R-forge is just a SVN repo server for me. When the build system was working properly across all OSes and current and devel versions of R, it was a wonderful resource. Hopefully normal service will be resumed soon.

Comment: I agree that things have been glitchy on R-forge but it works well enough that I continue to have 6 or 7 packages hosted there. It's not bad enough for me to have invested the time to move over to Rforge or to try a googlecode/github/etc. solution or a hybrid ...

Comment: Although an interesting question, I'm rather sure that it would never meet the requirements for a question as mentioned in the FAQ. Hence...

Answer (score 18):

R-forge is more popular, for whatever that's worth:

```
> nrow(available.packages(contriburl=contrib.url("http://www.r-forge.r-project.org")))
[1] 1272
> nrow(available.packages(contriburl=contrib.url("http://www.rforge.net")))
[1] 66
```

**Update** 3 March 2015: the numbers are now 1822 (r-forge) vs. 116 (rforge) vs. 6365 (CRAN).  Don't know how to detect/count R packages hosted on Github (maybe that's another question).

Comment: +1 For not answering the question with some useful R code!

Answer (score 18):

Neither is best, use github instead!

I use github because:

- github uses git which is a generally better version control system than svn.  As Richie mentions things like branching is easier, it's easier to work offline, and I find the command line interface to be a little more well thought out
- collaboration on github is vastly superior - it's easy to fork a package, make some improvements and then send your changes back to the original maintainer using a [pull request](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/)
- the servers are run by professionals and github.com is [rarely unavailable](http://status.github.com/).  R-forge is sometimes down for hours if something happens to the server in Austria
- It's easy to do [code reviews](https://github.com/blog/612-introducing-github-compare-view), especially helpful when working with new contributors.
- (personal opinion) The interface is clean and elegant and easy to navigate
- [github pages](http://pages.github.com/) make it easy to host a website about your package.
- built-in wiki is editable online and via git, and makes a good place for the community to [contribute documentation](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki)
- The issue tracking interface is vastly superior

The only downside of github is that it doesn't provide binaries.  I worked around that by developing the devtools package which makes it easy to install packages directly from github:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("scales", "hadley")
```

This requires that you have an R development environment, but this is actually pretty easy to set up, even on [windows](http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/)

Comment: What does github do that makes it a better R package manager?

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question of the differences between R-Forge and RForge.net.  You could have, at least, given some of the benefits of using github instead of the two repositories the OP mentioned.

Comment: @Anna: The main advantage is that is uses git rather the svn, so things like branching are easier.

Comment: I don't disagree with the advantages, and the `devtools` direct-install thing is great, but ... a lot of the users I work with would (I think) **not** find the R development environment "pretty easy to set up".  I admit I haven't tried it, but http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset would still be pretty scary.  Is http://www.murdoch-sutherland.com/Rtools/Rtools213.exe now pretty much self-contained?

Comment: Yes, setting up an R development environment on windows is now as easy as installing R.

Comment: One downside of github is that it doesn't provide checks against r-devel or r-patched...

Comment: @landroni github doesn't provide checking of anything. But if you use travis you can check against both released and devel

Comment: Indeed, it can be straightforward to have R packages checked on github. I had to follow the instructions in [Routinely testing your R package with Travis](http://jtleek.com/protocols/travis_bioc_devel/) (only for released), and use [metacran/r-builder](https://github.com/metacran/r-builder) (for both released and r-devel).

Answer (score 7):

Rforge.net is run by an R Core member and R-forge is supported by the R foundation, but they are both just package managers for R.

I don't see any significant differences except maybe the kinds of projects they host. It's possible that one site is hosting some projects unavailable on the other. At a glance, they seem to support the same source control (SVN), can be accessed in similar ways, and generally have similar goals.

I think you can just use either one so long as it's giving you what you want.